# After sending a POST request Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'am unable to find what goes worng with my code ...!when I send A post request  get an Error: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to  the client"
my model is - where I created comment_schema  whrer I have user,content,blog

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const comment_schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    blog: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Blog",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", comment_schema);
module.exports = Comment;
```

Controller is - Here is my postComment controller ,firstly I Find A Blog using req.params.blogId ,then I create a comment and save it ..! and last Associate Post with comment

```
exports.postComment = async (req, res) => {
  /// Find A Blog
  const blog = await Blog.findOne({ _id: req.params.blogId });
  // console.log(blog);
  // console.log(req.params.blogId);
  /// Create A Comment
  const comment = new Comment();
  comment.content = req.body.content;
  comment.user = req.body.user;
  // console.log(req.body.user);
  comment.blog = blog._id;
  comment.save((err, Blog_comment) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "something went wrong please try again ..!",
      });
    }
    res.json({ Blog_comment });
  });
  /// Associate Post with comment
  blog.comment.push(comment._id);
  blog.save((err, comment) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: "Saving Comment in DB failed",
      });
    }
    // res.status(200).json(comment);
    res.send(comment);
  });
  // res.send(comment);
};
```

And router is - this is my POST router ()

```
router.post("/blog/:blogId/postComment", postComment);
```

Full Error - I don't understand why I am getting this error

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to 
the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\git\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\git\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (E:\git\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\git\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at E:\git\backend\controllers\blog.js:196:9
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4842:16
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4865:21
    at model.<anonymous> (E:\git\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:502:7)
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:315:21
    at next (E:\git\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:209:27)
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:182:9
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:507:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) 
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4844:13
    at E:\git\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) 
{
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Is there anyone who can help...! please help I am unable to solve this issue ...! please help

Comment: You are sending response again once response is sent to request. You can observe that in comment.save callback and blog.save callback. You can respond once for a request.

Answer (score 0):

Below an solution for your script, the response is sent to the browser only when everything is executed or when the first error is thrown:

```js
exports.postComment = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    /// Find A Blog
    let blog = await Blog.findOne({ _id: req.params.blogId });
    /// Create A Comment
    let comment = new Comment();
    comment.content = req.body.content;
    comment.user = req.body.user;
    comment.blog = blog._id;
    comment = comment.save();
    /// Associate Post with comment
    blog.comment.push(comment._id);
    blog = await blog.save();
    res.send(blog );
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).json({
        error: "Saving Comment in DB failed",
    });
  }
};
```